# How is this statement evaluated and what is this kind of thing called?

Tags: c, gcc

```
#define FOO(val) \
({                                              \
   int b = val;                                 \
   printf("First, let's count to %d\n", val);   \
   for (int i = 1; i <= val; i++) {             \
      printf("%d...\n", i);                     \
   }                                            \
   b++;                                         \
   b;                                           \
})

int main() {
   int a = FOO(6);
   printf("a=%d\n", a);

   a = (4);     // straightforward, everyone should be familiar with this
   a = (4;);    // does not compile
   a = { 4; };  // does not compile
   a = ({ 4;}); // valid, a will equal 4


   return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around the above example.  How and why does the FOO macro work (the last statement appears to act as a return value)?  As far as syntax goes, what are the individual parts called and what other rules apply?

Comment: Hey, to confuse the matters further. `a = { 4 };` valid C++0x!

Comment: I'd like to note that the above example is probably wrong in a few respects. First, the argument to `printf` and the value tested against in the `for` loop should be `b`, not `val` to avoid potential side-effects of evaluating `val` multiple times. Secondly, `b` would be better named as `b_##__LINE__` so as to avoid potential clashes (though I don't suppose it greatly matters here since it goes out of scope).

Comment: @Chris, I'm pretty sure `b` is scope-local, that's the whole point of this construct. you are indeed right about reusing `val` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a [statement expression](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), and is not a part of standard ISO, however GCC supports it.

Quoting from the manual:

> A compound statement enclosed in parentheses may appear as an expression in GNU C. This allows you to use loops, switches, and local variables within an expression.
>
> ...
>
> The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct.

Comment: That link was the sort of thing I was looking for but was having trouble finding because I didn't know what things were called.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

That's using a GCC non-standard extension to allow return values from code blocks, mostly intended for macros. The last value inside a code block gets treated as a "return value".

A clear example of why this was needed is the usual `max` macro:

```
#define max(a,b) (a)<(b)?(b):(a)
```

Calling `max(new A(), new B())` causes 3 objects to be allocated, when in fact you only want 2 (contrived example, but the point is *one of the operands gets evaluated twice*).

With this extension you can instead write:

```
#define max(a,b) ({ typeof(a) _a=(a); typeof(b) _b=(b); _a<_b?_b:_a; })
```

In this case both operands get evaluated exactly once, just like a function, but with all benefits of macros (such as they are).

Comment: MSVC 6 would also "return" the last value in a function lacking a return statement. My highschool teacher thought it was fun to find compiler specific non-language-standard features to test us over.

Comment: Are you talking about comma lists? Those are quite different.

Answer (score 4):

Its a GCC extension called [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

#### One advice:

Whenever you see such weird syntax, must try compiling it with `-pedantic` option as well. You will immediately know, if its supported by the language specification or not.

For example, I compiled it with `-pedantic` option, and it says,

> warning: ISO C++ forbids braced-groups within expressions

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this isn't valid C++. Chapter 5 of the C++ standard defines what an ***expression*** is. `FOO(val)` sure as hell is not an *expression* according to that. Therefore, `int a = FOO(6);` is invalid

Comment: It is indeed not standard-compliant, this question should be tagged GCC.